# Word Finder regular expression, PHP & mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that I'm trying to run against a database of words. The query must return a word that contains another word, and letters given. It is in PHP and mySQL.

For example:

```
Word Given: Cruel
Letters Given: abcdty
```

In the database, I need to find the word "Cruelty" based on the letters given, and the word given. It needs to works both ways. So if I had "atni" for letters, "Anticruel" would appear if it existed in the database.

I have it half working but the result given is not correct:

```
SELECT word
FROM words
WHERE LOCATE(  "cruel", word ) >0
AND word !=  "cruel"
AND word
REGEXP  '[ybilteh]'
```

The result set from this query:

```
"anticruelty"
"crueler"
"cruelest"
"crueller"
"cruellest"
"cruelly"
"cruelness"
"cruelnesses"
"cruelties"
"cruelty"
```

Update!!!

Thanks to Benjamin Morel, this is getting much closer.

This query:

```
SELECT word
FROM words
WHERE LOCATE(  "t", word ) >0
AND word !=  "t"
AND word
REGEXP  '^[ybilteh]*t[ybilteh]*$'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Finds words correctly. But also includes words with double letters. Such as "Beet". When only 1 "e" is available.

Comment: ARe you working on a Scrabble-like game?

Comment: Perhaps? Not done yet. But it's comin.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Negative backreferences in MySQL REGEXP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122393/negative-backreferences-in-mysql-regexp)

Comment: The solution is extremely convoluted with pure MySQL alone, would it be an option to use MySQL to filter the easiest part and PHP for the rest?

Comment: @Alix - Absolutely. I just need it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT word
FROM words
WHERE word REGEXP '^[ybilteh]*cruel[ybilteh]*$'
AND word != 'cruel';
```

UPDATE: let's go refining with PHP, what about this?

```
$word = 'cruel';
$letters = 'ybilteh';

$items = array("anticruelty", "crueler", "cruelest",
    "crueller", "cruellest", "cruelly", "cruelness",
    "cruelnesses", "cruelties", "cruelty");

$letters = str_split($letters);
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $list = $letters;
    // remove the original word (once)
    $thisItem = preg_replace("/$word/", '', $item, 1); 
    for ($i=0; $i<strlen($thisItem); $i++) {
        $index = array_search($thisItem[$i], $list);
        if ($index === false) {
            continue 2; // letter not available
        }
        unset($list[$index]); // remove the letter from the list
    }
    echo "$item\n"; // passed!
}
```

Returns: cruelly, cruelty

You might probably find a better/simpler approach, but that should do the trick!

Comment: Works great, but now I have this problem.

For when a word is simply a letter. For example:

Word: T
Letters: ybilteh

Returns the word BEET (Double e)

Comment: You mean that each letter may appear only once?

Comment: No it just match the amount of the letter given. It returns BEET when only 1 "E" is present. I realize the regular expression can't do [ee]. Need to figure out a away around it

Comment: I can't think of any way to do that with MySQL, as advised by Alix above, you might want to use a MySQL query (this one) to get a raw list, then filter it with PHP.

Comment: awesome. I have something similar but this looks a bit cleaner. Thanks!